# Override enter for inner form fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to override what happens when a user presses enter on an inner form field. I do not want to disable enter.  I want to show a special pop up (bootstrap modal) and prevent form submission when user is updating value by pressing enter on the input field. I, also, still want `enter key` to try to submit the form when user presses it outside of the input field focus.  How do I do this?

Also, what exactly is this doing `action="javascript:`; Shouldnt it have a function name? Format is ftl.

```
<form id="tsp_form" class="form-vertical" autocomplete="off" action="javascript:;">

             <div class="step2">
                   <p class="title"><@spring.message "test.step2" /></p>
                   <div class="provider">
                          <div class="hideme" id="edit_provider">
                            <div style="display:inline;">
                              <input type="text" id="input_field" name="input_field" maxlength="16" value="${(tspProvider!'')?html}" style="display:inline;width:200px;margin-right:5px;" class="form-control"  />
                                                <input type="hidden" id="input_field" value="${(tspProvider!'')?html}" />
                                                <button id="edit_provider_submit" type=button class="btn btn-primary lineBtn" style="vertical-align: top;" role="button"><@spring.message "pac.save" /></button>
                                                <button id="edit_provider_cancel" type=button class="btn btn-default cancel lineBtn" style="vertical-align: top;" role="button"><@spring.message "pac.cancel" /></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input ... onkeydown="return event.key != 'Enter';">
```

or with JQuery

```
$('tsp_form:not([type="submit"])').keydown(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}});
```